# Example Clade Names in PhyloCode

Tags: taxonomy, phylogenetics

After looking through the [PhyloCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhyloCode), the only thing I found that looked like an example was in [Article 9, Chapter 4](https://www.ohio.edu/phylocode/art9.html):

> A node-based definition may be abbreviated "<A&B" or "<A&B&C&D [etc.]".
>
> A branch-based definition may be abbreviated ">A~Z" or ">A~Z∨Y∨X [etc.]".
>
> An apomorphy-based definition may be abbreviated ">M(A)".

Then from the following lines, I assume that that is actually how the names would appear in print:

> The system of abbreviations used here adopts the following conventions: > = "the most inclusive clade containing"; < = "the least inclusive clade containing"; & = "and";  ∨ = "or"; ~ = "but not"; A, B, C, etc. = species or specimens used as internal specifiers; Z, Y, X, etc. = species or specimens used as external specifiers; M = an apomorphy; () = "of" or "synapomorphic with that in"; >∇ = "the most inclusive crown clade containing"; <∇ = "the least inclusive crown clade containing". The inverted triangle meaning "crown clade" resembles the representation of a crown clade on a phylogenetic tree diagram.

I'm wondering if one could clarify what an actual real-world Clade name would be using the PhyloCode. Maybe just a few examples or even just one. For example, there is this fern [Equisetidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equisetidae), a subclass of [Polypodiopsida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptosporangiate_fern). Altogether it has this set of names:

```
Kingdom     Plantae
Subkingdom  Embryophyta
(unranked)  Tracheophyta
(unranked)  euphyllophytes
Class       Polypodiopsida
Subclass    Equisetidae
```

I am wondering how you would rewrite this using the PhyloCode. If it's too complicated or requires a bunch of additional work to initialize a basic set of codes or something, then that would be good to know too. But from the documents I've seen, it seems to suggest one can translate existing Linnaean classification terms to the PhyloCode somehow. My attempt at it without having gone thoroughly through the whole [document](https://www.ohio.edu/phylocode/PhyloCode4c.pdf) is this:

```
A = Plantae
B = Embryophyta
C = Tracheophyta
D = euphyllophytes
E = Polypodiopsida
F = Equisetidae
```

So the full name of it would be something like `A>B>C>D>E>F`. Or maybe it's more like this:

```
A = Plantae
A>B = Embryophyta
A>B>C = Tracheophyta
A>B>C>D = euphyllophytes
A>B>C>D>E = Polypodiopsida
A>B>C>D>E>F = Equisetidae
```

Looking for some help on better understanding how to translate existing Linnaean terms/species to PhyloCode. Wondering if you are actually renaming things like `Tracheophyta`, which has a *descriptive* Latin name, to `A>B>C`, which is a *non-descriptive* identifier. Thank you.